# Machine Learning Exercise Linear Regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, self-study, multiple-regression

This is a school exercise and I just don't get on the right track.

Data description:

- +- 1000 Samples test data.
- 1 Y column.
- 15 X columns.
- Y mean: ~6 max: 341 min: -221
- X: mean of each column around +- 1 (0.9, 1.05, 0.99 etc.). max over all X: 4.7 min over all X: -2.7

The target rsme should be around 15 but I just can't get below 20. I used every tool every library there is. Things I tried with sklearn: 
Models: LinearRegression,KernelRegression, KernelRidge, BayesianRidge. 
Feature selection: PolynomialFeatures up to degree 5 but everything over 2 mostly the rsme gets worse. from 1 to degree 2 is the most significant reduction in rsme visible.

A few plots: 
[image: Y plot]
[image: Sorted Y plot mby more interesting?]

The one below is sorted for Y

I tried to post more pictures below of the x y relations but I can't here because I'm only allowed to post 2.

I should mention that we had only linear regression already and it should be kinda solvable with that they told.

Comment: This is a question that requires the self-study tag.

Comment: did you try removing variables from the model that are not well correlated with y? did you try adding interaction terms (e.g. x1*x2)?

Answer (score 1):

Look closely to the distribution of your data. The mean is around 6 while the max and min values are 341 and -221 respectively. This suggests that there a number of outliers in your dataset and nothing is more worse for a regression problem than outliers. So, you need to remove the outliers first. Then you should standardize the data values by using a scaler. After these, you should try a regression model.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I used the Scaler class from sklearn to Scale my X. And for the outliners i trained my model then removed the top 10% of wrongest predicted X and trained again. should i remove the outliners before i train?

Comment: Yes you can remove all the outliers in the way you are doing but I find Tukey's method more reliable. Remove outliers using Tukey's method before training

Comment: @Sim did you end up getting a better result after removing outliers?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more pictures to the relation between x & y
[image]

[image]